# Joomla plugin to override table prefix

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, jdatabase

**Overview:** I have a single Joomla website that have various copies of the database tables all in the same database, but with different table prefixes.

Depending on which user is accessing the site, i need to alter which joomla table prefix is used in order to display the relevant tables.

This has to be site wide.

**Problem:** with a core code hack i can alter the prefix as needed, but would prefer this as a plugin.

With the plugin i can get the prefix, using $db->getPrefix(), and i can set an immediate instance of the connection using $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option ). But this is not site wide and is overwritten by the standard $db = JFactory::getDbo().

So i need a system plugin that will replace every instance of a table prefix as it is run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Shaun and welcome to JSE. I'm very curious as to why you'd need to change the table prefix per user. Could you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to do this from within a plugin, this is because Joomla starts accessing the database way before loading the plugins.

The only way to do this is from within the `configuration.php` file, where you should have the logic (you should create a function called `getTablePrefix` there). You must ensure though that Joomla cannot write to this file, because if it does so, then it will destroy your changes.

I have thought about doing this through the `defines.php` file, but it can't be done there because it is loaded before the configuration is loaded.

Excellent question by the way, but I'm also curious on why you need to have a different set of tables for each user. Maybe the best solution would be to rethink the whole logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to do it is to add your custom `class JDatabaseDriverCustom extends JDatabaseDriverMySql` for example and there you'll be able to go with a few options:

- write user-depended logic right inside of the driver;
- call some function that you will write in another place;

Anyway, think about: do you really need the site to depend on the user, or on something like IP or anything not related to Joomla. This way you'll be able to write `__constructor()` inside your config file and place the logic right there and change `$this->db_prefix`.